# About view models and interfaces

Tags: mvvm, interface, view, model

I'm developing a WPF Prism application, and everything is working fine. My view models all have interfaces, which are injected by MEF.

However, I don't really understand the benefit of interfaces for view models. After all, a view is tied to its view model, so I think there will never be other implementations.

Actually, I also have interfaces for my views. It seems that this is also overkill?

So my question is: can't I just remove all view and view model interfaces and inject the views and view models directly? Is there any reason to keep interfaces for views and view models?

Thx,
L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfacing your VieWModels gives you the benefit of mocking them in a test, interfacing your Views looks like some overkill indeed. You won't interchange your views and UI testing can be done on mocks of your ViewModel so you won't really need to interface them I think.

Comment: Why mock your ViewModels in test? I just use the actual ViewModel.

Comment: I would mock the ViewModels to put expectations in them. That way I know how the Views should look when testing them. I could also write test that would fill the ViewModels with data and provide them during testing. It's indeed quite the same.

Comment: thanks, so am I correct to say that there is not really a lot of added value in interfacing view models, because of: 1. We don't need to mock them, because it's the view model itself that has to be tested. 2. Therefore, mocking out a sub view model doesn't make much sense, as we also want to test the actual one. 3. In order to test the views, we just fill the actual view models with data. 4. As a view is coupled to its view model, there will always be 1 implementation.

Answer (score 10):

It is an overkill. I understand that you may want to mock your ViewModels, but I think it's more important to be practical. Plus, why would you even need to mock your ViewModels? Any logic that needs to be mocked should be put into a service class IMHO.

Comment: That was indeed also my first thought. It seems the advantage is that, if you have multiple view models, you can test one of them and mock out the others. I just wonder if I will ever do that... most logic is indeed in 'services' that are injected and can be replaced my mock implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest reason I can think of for interfaces for ViewModels would be that you can write mocks that implement those interfaces for use while unit testing. Since one ViewModel may talk to another, it enables you to stub out the second ViewModels behaviour when testing the first.

The MVVM pattern makes it easier to unit test the classes as it separates data and control from the UI layer (which is harder to write unit tests for). Personally, I don't write interfaces for my views though.